# can not fetch data from table through foreign key using HQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

i have a class

```
public class HobbyHome:Establishment
```

{

```
public virtual ICollection<HobbyHomeAddress> HobbyHomeAddressList { set; get; }
public virtual ICollection<HobbyDeveloper> HobbyDeveloperList { set; get; }
public virtual ICollection<HobbyDetail> HobbyDetailList { set; get; }
```

}

inside the hobbyDetail:

```
  [Key]
    public virtual int HobbyDetailID { get; set; }


   // public virtual int HobbyId { get; set; }     
    public virtual HobbyMasters Hobbymaster { get; set; }
    public virtual Course course { get; set; }
    public virtual StudyMedium StudyMedium { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Fees { get; set; }
```

}

ican save my data in both the tables...but while fetching hobbydetail through HobbyHomeId...i'm getting error as can not find Field

the mapping file for Hobbyhome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

 <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly ="HobbyHomes"  namespace="HobbyHomes.Model" >
  <class name ="HobbyHome" table="HobbyHome">
   <id name="EstablishmentId" column="HobbyHomeId">
        <generator class="native"/>
   </id>
  <property name="Name"/>

  <set name="HobbyHomeAddressList">
        <key column="HobbyHomeId" foreign-key="fk_HobbyHomeAddress_HobbyHomeId"/>
      <one-to-many class ="HobbyHomes.Model.HobbyHomeAddress"/>
      </set>
      <set name="HobbyDeveloperList">
           <key column="HobbyHomeId" foreign-key="fk_HobbyDeveloper_HobbyHomeId"/>
           <one-to-many class ="HobbyHomes.Model.HobbyDeveloper"/>
   </set>
   <set name="HobbyDetailList">
       <key column="HobbyHomeId" foreign-key="fk_HobbyDetail_HobbyHomeId"/>
       <one-to-many class ="HobbyHomes.Model.HobbyDetail"/>
  </set>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

here is my function for fetch the data:

```
  public HobbyDetail FetchbyHobbyId(int id)
    {
        log.Debug("Start");
        ISession session = DataAccessLayerHelper.OpenWriterSession();
        ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
        HobbyDetail hobbydetail = null;
        try
        {

            ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(HobbyDetail))
               .Add(Restrictions.Eq("HobbyHomeId", id));

            hobbydetail = criteria.UniqueResult<HobbyDetail>();

            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (SessionException ex)
        {
            if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
                transaction.Rollback();

            log.Error(ex);
            hobbydetail = null;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.Dispose();

            if (session != null && session.IsConnected)
                session.Close();

            log.Debug("End");
        }
        return hobbydetail;
    }
```

can sumbody please help me with this....

Answer (score 0):

HQL is an object oriented query language. You can only use identifiers that exist in your class model.

You could add a back reference from the HobbyDetail to the HobbyHome making the reference bidirectional.

You could also use a subquery to get all the details that are in the list of the HobbyHome. This is easier with HQL than with criteria.

On the other hand it is much easier to just load the HobbyHome.

```
        ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(HobbyHome))
           .Add(Restrictions.IdEq(id));

        var home = criteria.UniqueResult<HobbyHome>();
        var details = home.HobbyDetailList;
```

Comment: Well i did this bt i'm only able to get hobbyhomeid and name for that particular hobbyhome... bt not other details of other class...do i have to write a join as well while fetching hobbyhome??

Comment: I don't understand. What means "i'm only able to get hobbyhomeid and name for that particular hobbyhome"? Are other properties null after the query?

Comment: The id and name is coming from inherited class bt i need data for class hobbydetail who's ICollection is made in hobbyhome class....how can i get that class data??

Comment: I still don't understand. Coming from inherited class?? The ICollection is *made* in HobbyHome?? Can't you just say what you are doing and what you get?

Comment: Icollection are in Hobbyhome only but wen i fetch by the code u wrote....it does not give me the Icollection information....They are cuming as "null"....i'm not able to fetch data of the Icollection class which is made like
public virtual ICollection<HobbyHomeAddress> HobbyHomeAddressList { set; get; }

Comment: But you are accessing the collection from within the session? After the session is closed, lazy loaded data is not loaded anymore. (Although is should throw an exception instead of returning null.)

Comment: :at time of fetching Hobbyhome it gives only the value of its fields not the Icollection values.....for iCollection values it gives nothing...:(

Comment: I don't no. never seen a collection loaded by NH being null.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to write an HQL for this .... may be i'm wrong sumwhere....